# Run a job after 30 minutes when a specific field of object was set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jobs

I need to run a job that sends email to the user when a contest's field named `published_at` will be set. So I have a `Contest` model and a method that runs a job:

```
class Contest < ApplicationRecord

  after_create :send_contest

  private

  def send_contest
    SendContestJob.set(wait: 30.minutes).perform_later(self)
  end

end
```

But the job will run even if `published_at` field is blank. Validating the field to be present is not an option because `published_at` can be set later. So are there any solutions how can I run the job after setting the field? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) might be useful here. With it, you can inspect what fields are about to change/have been changed:

```
person.name # => "bob"
person.name = 'robert'
person.save
person.previous_changes # => {"name" => ["bob", "robert"]}
```

So, say, if `published_at_changed?` returns true, you schedule the job.

Comment: When I do in the console `user.name = 'Name'` save it and then check `user.name_changed?` it gives me false, but if I don't save the user with `user.save`, and then check if the name was changed, then I get true.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi: read the rest of the methods, you'll surely find something for your situation

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi: actually, read this very answer, the code in it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `after_create` you can use `before_save` which is fired both for new and existing records.

The `if:` and `unless:` options allow you to specify conditions that need to be met for a callback to be called, you can pass a Proc, Lambda or the name of a method to be called.

```
class Contest < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :send_contest, if: -> { published_at.present? && published_at_changed? }

  # or
  before_save :send_contest, if: :publishable?

  private

  def send_contest
    SendContestJob.set(wait: 30.minutes).perform_later(self)
  end

  def publishable?
    published_at.present? && published_at_changed?
  end
end
```

As recommended by Sergio Tulentsev you can use [ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) to check for changes to the value of the column. Be sure to read the docs carefully though as there are plenty of gotchas.

Comment: `field_changed?` are no longer true after save.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev true, changed to `before_save`.

Comment: But your answer also uses AM::Dirty. `field_changed?` comes from there :)

Comment: I know, I just wanted to provide some context of where it comes from. @SergioTulentsev